# How to grep in the beginning of line using a string which is stored in a variable

Tags: shell-script, grep

I have a shell script; say `test.sh` with the following contents:

```
for j in *_seqs.txt; do  

    while read line; do

    count_of_occurences=$(grep "^$line" $j)
    echo $count_of_occurences
    done < $1

done
```

and a couple of files in the same folder; say

```
1_seqs.txt
2_seqs.txt
3_seqs.txt
4_seqs.txt
5_seqs.txt
```

The contents of say `1_seqs.txt` may look like

```
AAA0030309
3300AAA009
00AAA33030
AAA0022033
```

I have another file, say `alphabets.txt` with following contents

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

I want to look the contents of `alphabets.txt` in all the `*_seqs.txt` using the shell script `test.sh`. And I want to find if say `AAA` appears in the beginning of a line of say `1_seqs.txt`
 and so on.

I am unable to do so when I run the script like this

`sh test.sh alphabets.txt`

For some reason, `grep` is unable to look at the beginning when the string is stored in the variable `$line` within `test.sh`.

My output of the script should be

```
AAA0030309
AAA0022033
```

Comment: What happens instead? One thing you're missing is quoting of your variables (so for example `$count_of_occurences` will undergo word splitting). FWIW you might want to look at alternatives like `sed 's/^/^/' alphabets.txt | grep -f- *_seqs.txt`

Comment: Your expected output is at odds with your shell script.  In the script you are outputting the number of times the patterns can be found, but you expect the output the contents of the lines that matches? Could you clarify, and also show what actually happens, [as steeldriver requested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517228/how-to-grep-in-the-beginning-of-line-using-a-string-which-is-stored-in-a-variabl#comment955694_517228)?  Please [edit] the question rather than replying in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script almost already does what you want. You don't need the `grep` capture which just complicates the printing:

```
#!/bin/bash

for j in *_seqs.txt; do  
  while read line; do
      grep "^$line" "$j"
  done < "$1"
done
```